# Installing Ruby using rbenv on Deepin 15.10

Tags: ruby, rbenv

Trying to install Ruby using rbenv (or any other installer I tried RVM and ruby-install) fails and gives this error

```
$ rbenv install 2.6.3

> Downloading ruby-2.6.3.tar.bz2...
-> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.6/ruby-2.6.3.tar.bz2
Installing ruby-2.6.3...
ruby-build: use readline from homebrew

BUILD FAILED (Deepin 15.10 using ruby-build 20190423)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/ruby-build.20190507002901.29361
Results logged to /tmp/ruby-build.20190507002901.29361.log

Last 10 log lines:
    from /tmp/ruby-build.20190507002901.29361/ruby-2.6.3/lib/rubygems/package.rb:44:in `<top (required)>'
    from /tmp/ruby-build.20190507002901.29361/ruby-2.6.3/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /tmp/ruby-build.20190507002901.29361/ruby-2.6.3/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /tmp/ruby-build.20190507002901.29361/ruby-2.6.3/lib/rubygems/installer.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /tmp/ruby-build.20190507002901.29361/ruby-2.6.3/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /tmp/ruby-build.20190507002901.29361/ruby-2.6.3/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:703:in `<module:RbInstall>'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:639:in `<main>'
uncommon.mk:364: recipe for target 'do-install-all' failed
make: *** [do-install-all] Error 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

FINALLY FIXED IT !!
I had to use `brew unlink openssl`
then `sudo apt-get install -y libssl-dev zlib1g-dev`
then i tried `rbenv install 2.6.3` and IT WORKED !

Comment: I was also getting a similar `recipe for target 'do-install-all' failed` error message when installing ruby 2.7.1 with rbenv. But after installing `libssl-dev`, I was successfully able to install ruby 2.7.1. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$ TMPDIR=~/tmp/ rbenv install 2.6.3
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [what this site is about](https://stackoverflow.com/about) and "[How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)" before answering a question.